# Firebase dynamic link does not navigate to ios app/ appstore from facebook post in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I have to implement navigation from facebook post to my native iOS app or app store if the app is not installed. For that, I have tried Facebook APP Link feature but it did not work. Then I created Firebase Dynamic link and post it on facebook app directly. After tapping on posted link, it shows one pop up saying **"Leave Facebook? This webpage is trying to open an app outside of Facebook. Are you sure you want to open it?"**
After tapping on Yes, it does nothing. I have cross verified the created link with **https://app_id.app.goo.gl/apple-app-site-association** It shows associated bundle id, team id, app store id.
Can anyone please suggest me the proper pathway to implement deep linking with facebook post to the app? 
Also, can we test deep linking with the app which is not on the App Store?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: FB does not redirect from deeplink
becaues it uses its own in-app browser so it can not read your URLscheme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook doesn't like users to leave their app. They stopped supporting App Links in their iOS app almost a year ago, and have never supported Universal Links (which is what Firebase Dynamic Links uses).

The only workaround is to send users to a landing page with a CTA button, and put *another* deep link behind that button (on a different domain than the one on which you're hosting this landing page). It's an extra step for the user, but currently the only option. [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team) does this via the [Deepviews](https://dev.branch.io/features/deepviews/overview/) feature. Dynamic Links currently doesn't have an equivalent, so you'd need to build something yourself.

Comment: I have implemented firebase dynamic link with Facebook with com.companyname.example bundle id. How can I be assure it will work with my apple store bundle id.? Please help. Currently it always navigate app to appstore though my iphone have same app with same bundle id. Please advise.